# Counting the number of rows that contains specific numbers in specific cells

Tags: matrix, counting

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of rows in a matrix that contains specific elements in specific cells.

For example, suppose I have the following matrix

`Data={{1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,1,0,0}}`

What I want to find is the number of rows that is consistent with the following list:

`list1={1,Null,Null,1}`

So, in the data, `{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1}}`
is consistent with the `list1`, so the output should be 4.

Another example is if `list2={1,1,1,1}`, then the output should be 2. 
If `list3={1,Null,Null,Null}`, then we should have 6 as there are 6 rows starting with 1.

How can this situation be efficiently programmed? The length of each row is the same in the data and I have a very large size of the zero-one matrix.

Comment: Just to add to the answers below: you can do *strict* filtering with `Alternatives` (`|`) and `Repeated[]` e.g. `Count[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1},  {0, 1, 0, 0}}, {1, Repeated[0 | 1, {2}], 1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1={1,Null,Null,1}
sel = Map[If[# === Null, __, #] &, list1];
Cases[Data, sel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
list2 = {1, 1, 1, 1};
sel = Map[If[# === Null, __, #] &, list2]
Cases[Data, sel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
list3 = {1, Null, Null, Null};
sel = Map[If[# === Null, __, #] &, list3]
Cases[Data, sel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0,0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};

Cases[data, {1, _, _, 1}] // Length
(* 4 *)

Cases[data, {1, 1, 1, 1}] // Length
(* 2 *)

Cases[data, {1, _, _, _}] // Length
(* 6 *)
```

Comment: You can use `Count[]` instead of `Length[Cases[(* stuff *)]]`.